# Use dashing style and color as legends for Show

Tags: plotting, legending, graphics

When plotting the following,

```
p1 = Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Dashing[Tiny],PlotRange->{0,2}]
p2 = Plot[{x + 1, x^2 + 1}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Dashing[Medium]]
Show[p1, p2]
```

in Show I want to use dash style to indicated "intercept 0" and "intercept 1", and color style to indicate "linear" and "non-linear". Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need. What are intercept 0 and 1? And what do you mean with color style/dash style? Do you want the two linear functions to be solid and the two quadratic function to be dashed?
Please clarify what you need in the question by editing it.

Comment: @Fraccalo the two curves in p1 both have an intercept 0, and the two curvees in p2 both have an intercept 1. Because of your question, I am no longer sure whether this is a correct statement.

Comment: @Glenn Do you mean how to add labels?

Comment: @Collwater, I think what I want is to show differences in the most straightforward way. I do not have a preference for label or legends here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
legends = Plot[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Directive[Dashing[Tiny], Black], Directive[Dashing[Medium], Black],
                    ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]], ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]]},
    PlotLegends -> {"Intercept 0", "Intercept 1", "Linear", "Nonlinear"}];

Show[p1, p2, legends, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]